# Node.js coding challenge - what files to submit

Tags: node.js, submission

I'm doing a coding challenge in node where I need to submit the answer as a .zip file. Which files do I need to submit? The files in my folder are:

1. server.js (main file)
2. package.json
3. package-lock.json
4. node-modules (folder)

I have not started the challenge yet because there is a time limit, so I don't know if further details will be provided in the problem description. So, in general, what files do I need to submit and how does the person know that my solution is writtien in Node?

Comment: You'll need to ask the folks running the challenge, regarding what to submit. No possible way for us to know here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you need to refer to what your challenge says, but in terms of what a baseline Node project should consist of — which I think is what you're really asking here — you just need your js source files and package.json.

If you have a .js Node file like your server.js and a package.json, it can be run with the following commands:

`$ npm install`

`$ node server.js`

Your package.json file should include a "main" item which specifies server.js as the project's launch file, or whatever file you want it to launch from.

package-lock.js can also be included, as it will lock down your dependencies exactly. node_modules is not necessary to include because package.json and package-lock.json will be used to generate node_modules.

There's nothing else that a Node project *must* have included, although a README.md file is good practice to have as well. You could also specify in the README that this is a Node project and add the commands required to run it, which would be good to do if your challenge does not directly specify that all projects should be in Node.

Answer (score 0):

A folder with just:

1. server.js (main file)
2. package.json

Should be enough for them to try it. I wouldn't submit the node_modules folder, because it can contain modules compiled on your machine that won't work on their.

Maybe put a README.txt to describe how to run the solution.